# OpenGL GLSL Cel Shading and Outline algorithm

Tags: opengl, glsl, outline

I have successfully implemented a cel shader using glsl. But my problem is about outlining everything and every example of opengl on the internet is pretty old, doesn't match current technology, so slow techniques etc... So I couldn't find anyway to do it in glsl. I thought about some ideas like colorizing least intensive areas black but there is not even enough explanation about gl_Vertex, gl_Position and eye positions. So, since every technique is too old, I have finally decided to ask someone about this outline problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would use some kind of edge detection filter on the zbuffer (could potentially be combined with edge detection on the color buffer) and then modulate the framebuffer with the (inverted) result. One of the most common edge detection filters is the sobel operator:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator

**EDIT:** Another cheap way of doing this is to before you render the ordinary mesh draw a black copy of the mesh with cull facing inverted and the vertices slightly moved in the direction of the normal. This is probably what they did in XIII, I'm also pretty sure this is how it was done in Jet Set Radio.

**EDIT2:** If you want the thickness of the outline to be constant regardless of the distance to the viewer, you should scale the amount you move the vertices with this distance.

Comment: i think it is too expensive for a simple outline.

Comment: What kind of hardware are you targeting?

Comment: like x1650pro equivelant. XIII game somehow does it with the requirement of really old hardware.

Comment: thanks for amazing answer, i will try and report you about thanks

Comment: The backface drawing method is also found in Okami.  It couldn't even be done with shaders, there.  It was just modeled.

Comment: Question for an extra +1: Can the reversed-normals approach be implemented via a geometry shader?

Comment: If you're referring to the scaled model approach it can easily be implemented in a vertex shader.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at glPolygonOffset?

I've used it to draw outlines on top of filled polygons.

http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glPolygonOffset.xml

Comment: Yet you don't say anything about your approach, which is not obvious, and which makes the answer not very useful. I'll give your point back when you do :)